# ProxyPass not working - Apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, apache2, proxypass

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin callumokane123@gmail.com
ServerName server.maniabots.xyz
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

The above, which I have used before on other servers does not want to work on my server and is just listing the default directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable proxy modules on Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests

# restart the apache service
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```